# Bluemix Load Balancer Algorithm

Tags: load-balancing, ibm-cloud, autoscaling

What algorithm is used to balance HTTP load among several instances running on Bluemix? It seems I can use auto-scaling service to scale horizontally, and want to know what algorithm is used when balancing the load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud Foundry uses round-robin load balancing to distribute requests across the running instances of your app.